# How to get post permission publish_actions in facebook sdk 4+ with an perfect example

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i am not able to get publish_actions permission of facebook sdk4+ i am facing problem and i found there is no proper example available. if any one has the solution do post here. i found that old version solution are shown by everyone but did not found solution for sdk4+ .

```
       LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
        Log.e("publish_action", "asking_for_permission");

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("publish_actions"))
                {

                    Log.e("publish_action", "permission_activated");
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    try {
                        Log.e("publish_action", "permission_activated_inside_try");
                        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                .setBitmap(image)
                                .setCaption("A post from Android code")
                                .build();

                        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                .addPhoto(photo)
                                .addPhoto(photo)
                                .addPhoto(photo)
                                .build();


                        ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                                Log.e("successfull", "photo_uploaded");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                Log.e("canceled", "photo_uploaded_cancled");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                                Log.e("error", "photo_upload_error");
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("onCancel");
                Log.e("publish_action", "cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.e("publish_action", "error = " + exception.getMessage());
                System.out.println("onError");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this [link](http://mrbool.com/integrating-android-applications-with-facebook/33934) you must try this url this is a perfect demo for publish_actions permission to facebokk it was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solution was

```
if (!AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("PERMISSION_THAT_YOU_NEED")) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions((Activity) viewInterface.getContext(), Arrays.asList("PERMISSION_THAT_YOU_NEED"));
        return;
```

You need to return after using logInWithPublishPermissions(), because user may not allow you to use it, but your code will continue to run. And if user provide access to this permission, code will complete successfully next time.

Try this, hope it help to you.